# Accurate modular arithmetic with double precision

Tags: c++, performance, algorithm, floating-point

I have a function `ProdBigMod` which computes the product of two double precise numbers \$x_1\$, \$x_2\$ (both of which are less than \$2^{53} - 1\$) and subsequently finds the remainder \$\mod p\$ (where \$p\$ is prime). I am not at liberty to use external libraries and must use double data type.

> The main challenge comes into play when the product of \$x_1\$ and \$x_2\$ exceeds \$2^{53} - 1\$.

As @TobySpeights points out, 53 is important because it is the number of `mantissa` bits (also called `significand` hence the name of the constant `Significand53`) for double data types (see [Double-precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format)). We can eliminate some of these issues by first ensuring that both \$x\$s are less than \$p\$ (this is achieved by immediately applying `std::fmod`).  In fact, when `p < sqrt(2^53 - 1)`, we know the product `prodX = x1 * x2 < 2^53 - 1`. To deal with the case when `p > 2^53 - 1` and `prodX > 2^53 - 1`, we can take advantage of some properties of modular arithmetic.

Namely:

$$(x_1 \cdot x_2) \pmod p = x_1 \cdot (x_{12} + x_{22} + ... + x_{n2}) \pmod p$$

Where \$(x_{12} + x_{22} + ... + x_{n2}) = x_2\$.

This gives:

$$\big( x_1 \cdot x_{12} \pmod p \big) \space\space + \space\space \big(x_1 \cdot x_{22} \pmod p\big) \space\space + ... +  \space\space \big(x_1 \cdot x_{n2} \pmod p\big)$$

Now, given that each of the \$x_{i2}\$ (`chunkSize` below) are the same except for possibly the final one (i.e. \$x_{n2}\$), we can compute the following once:

$$x_1 \cdot x_{12} \pmod p \space\space = \space\space x_1 \cdot chunkSize \pmod p \space\space = \space\space chunkMod$$

To find the final \$x_{n2}\$ we first have to determine how many \$x_{i2}\$s will go into \$x_2\$:

```
numChunkMods = floor(x2 / chunkSize)
```

Now we can easily obtain `xn2`:

```
xn2 = (x2 - chunkSize * numChunkMods)  ==>>  part2 = x1 * xn2 (mod p)
```

Putting this altogether, `Eq. (1)` can be reduced to:

```
x1 * x2 (mod p) = (chunkMod * numChunkMods) + part2 (mod p)
```

This is a good start, but doesn't get us completely out of the woods, since we don't know for sure that the product `numChunkMods * chunkMod < 2^53 - 1`. To get around this, we continue the process above by setting `x1 = chunkMod` and `x2 = numChunkMods`, until the product is less than `2^53 - 1`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

const double Significand53 = 9007199254740991.0;
const double SqrtSig53 = std::floor(std::sqrt(Significand53));

double PositiveMod(double x, double m) {
    if (x < 0)
        x = x + ceil(std::abs(x) / m) * m;
    else if (x > m)
        x = std::fmod(x, m);
    return x;
}

double ProdBigMod(double x1, double x2, double p) {
    double result = 0, prodX;

    x1 = PositiveMod(x1, p);
    x2 = PositiveMod(x2, p);
    prodX = x1 * x2;

    if (prodX < p) {
        result = prodX;
    } else if (p < SqrtSig53 || prodX < Significand53) {
        result = std::fmod(prodX, p);
    } else {
        double numChunkMods, part1 = Significand53;
        double chunkSize, chunkMod, part2;

        while (part1 >= Significand53) {
            chunkSize = std::floor(Significand53 / x1);  // Ensures chunkMod < 2^53 - 1
            chunkMod = std::fmod(x1 * chunkSize, p);
            numChunkMods = std::floor(x2 / chunkSize);
            part2 = std::fmod((x2 - chunkSize * numChunkMods) * x1, p);
            part1 = numChunkMods * chunkMod;
            x1 = chunkMod;
            x2 = numChunkMods;
            result = std::fmod(result + part2, p);
        }

        result = std::fmod(part1 + result, p);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Here is an example of how to call the function:

```
int main() {
    double test = ProdBigMod(914806066069, 497967734853, 732164213243);
    std::cout  << std::fixed;
    std::cout << test << "\n";
    return 0;
}

Output: 85635829849.000000
```

I have compared the above on random samples of numbers in the range `10^12` with a `gmp` analog and it seems to give correct results. However, I'm not exactly sure if my logic or implementation is bullet-proof. I'm also wondering if it could be more efficient.

Here is an online "Big Number Calculator" that you can test the results against: https://defuse.ca/big-number-calculator.htm

For example, input `(914806066069 * 497967734853) % 732164213243` into the expression field and click "Calculate".

Comment: Do you have constraints about only using `double`? If you could convert to uint128_t... This reminds me a bit of double-double libraries, where before FMA (are you allowed to use fma?) multiplication would split each operand into a sum of short-mantissa numbers.

Comment: @MarcGlisse, for this particular case, I'm constrained to `double`. Besides, even without this constraint, I'm interested in improvements, as insights to this problem can be applied to other situations dealing precision.

Comment: Well, using one multiplication and one fma, you can rewrite a*b to c+d, so if you have already written AddBigMod...

Comment: @MarcGlisse Sadly, some `fma()` are not that precise: [Is my fma() broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42172145/2410359).  IMO, that case is non-compliant per the intent of the function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Integer-ness

It should be made more clear that `ProdBigMod()` is to only work with whole number values and not the full range of `double` including values with fractional parts, [NaN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN) and infinites.

I would expect code to detect non-whole number values and exit/complain as needed - perhaps return NaN.

## Off-by-one:

"... when `p < sqrt(2^53 - 1)` ..." should be "... when `p <= sqrt(2^53)` ...".
This allows for a slightly larger `p`.

Recall that `something mod p` will be at most, `p - 1`.

This is reflected in the incorrect code: `x > m` --> `x >= m`

```
double PositiveMod(double x, double m) {
    if (x < 0)
        ...
    // else if (x > m)
    else if (x >= m)
        x = std::fmod(x, m);
    return x;
}
```

and

```
// } else if (p < SqrtSig53 || ...
} else if (p <= SqrtSig53 || ...
```

## Portability

Use of `Significand53` and other code relies on `double` as a [binary64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format).  A simple test would prevent a number of errant compilations, even if not increase portability.

```
#if DBL_MANT_DIG != 53
  #error TBD code
#endif
```

## Alternative precision test.

Code does `prodX = x1 * x2;` and various tests when code could test `FE_INEXACT` after the multiplication.

```
feclearexcept(FE_INEXACT);
prodX = x1 * x2
if (fetestexcept(FE_INEXACT)) Handle_inexact_product();
```

## Questionable code

I am not confident `x = x + ceil(std::abs(x) / m) * m;` work as expected for all `x, m`, especially when the math quotient is just over a whole number, but rounds down before `ceil()`.  Clearer alternative:

```
double PositiveMod(double x, double m) {
  double y = std::fmod(x, m);
  if (y < 0.0) {
    y = (m < 0) ? y - m : y + m;
  }
  return y;
}
```

## Code alternate:

Use 64-bit or better integer math.  See `mulmodmax()` in [Modular exponentiation without range restriction](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/187257/29485).  Good for at least 19 decimal digit integers vs. 12 here.

## fmod() correctness.

Note: The specification of `std::fmod()` does not require the result to be the best possible answer, yet with *IEEE Standard 754* adherence, it is.  A good library would implement an exact result.  Ref:
 [Is fmod() exact when y is an integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20928253/2410359)
.

---

## Conclusion

In all, using FP math to solve an integer problem has various unexpected corner concerns and so is hard to insure code is right for *all* `x1,x2,p`.

Comment: Great answer. How about 'at most, 1 less than p' -> 'at most \$ p - 1 \$'? it caught me off guard for a second.

Comment: @Coal_ OK - answer amended.

Comment: `mulmodmax` is a really nice function, however it is a bit esoteric.  I have spent a good bit of time figuring out how it works and understand it, however I don't think it is immediately obvious to the reader. An explanation would be nice if you have time. Thanks for the thorough schooling!

Comment: @JosephWood Perhsp [Avoiding overflow working modulo p](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48722304/2410359) would help.

Comment: I think your off-by-one is itself off by one: `p <= sqrt(2^53 - 1)` or `p < sqrt(2^53)` (if I'm right that 2^53 is the lowest value that can't be exactly represented).  That said, we know sqrt(2^53) is not an integer, so I'm splitting hairs here.

Comment: @TobySpeight 1) 2^53 _can_ be exactly represented in double.  2^53 + 1 cannot.  2) True about "hairs", yet if N was even, rather than 53, then  `p` could be `2^(N/2)` as `fmod(a,p)` would be less than `2^(N/2)` and `a*a` does not even meet `2^N`.  3) As answered, using FP for an integer problem, has various unexpected corners.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like there is another implementation using `std::fma`, which looks pretty simple.
It is mentioned at [Modular SIMD arithmetic in Mathemagix (page 18)](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1407/1407.3383.pdf#page=18).

```
// https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1407/1407.3383.pdf#page=18
double ProdBigMod(double a, double b, double m) {
  // a, b, m - are integers within [0; 2**53-1], a < m, b < m
  double p = a * b;
  double r1 = std::fma(a, b, -p);
  double q = std::rint(p / m);
  double r2 = -std::fma(q, m, -p);
  if (r1 < 0) {
    r1 += m;
  }
  if (r2 < 0) {
    r2 += m;
  }
  double r = r1 - m + r2;
  if (r < 0) {
    r += m;
  }
  return r;
}
```

Would be nice to test efficiency against the original code.

*UPDATE*: the code was fixed to work within the range correctly

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! You have presented an alternative solution, but haven't reviewed the code. Please [edit] to show what aspects of the question code prompted you to write this version, and in what ways it's an improvement over the original.  It may be worth (re-)reading [answer].